# Getting error while creating account with the help of LDS function createRecord

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, error, create-records, lds

error is :
enhancedErrorType
:
"RecordError"
message
:
"An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again."

**Code is**
js code:

```
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
export default class AdpaterFunctionDemo extends LightningElement {
    @api
    naam = 'default';

    handleInput(ev){
        this.naam = ev.target.value;
    }
    handleSubmit(event){
        let recordInput = {
            apiName : ACCOUNT_OBJECT.objectApiName,
            fields : { 
                [NAME_FIELD.FieldApiName] : this.naame

            }

        };
      createRecord(recordInput)
      .then(account =>{
        console.log("account record created");
        console.log(this.naam);
      })
      .catch(error =>{
        console.log('Error occured');
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
}
```

**component code:**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="account Creat">
        <div>
        <lightning-input label="Enter name" value={naam} onchange={handleInput}></lightning-input>
        <lightning-button label="save" onclick={handleSubmit}></lightning-button>
        <p>naam hai {naam}</p>
    </div>
    </lightning-card> 
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[NAME_FIELD.FieldApiName] : this.naame
```

Should be:

```
[NAME_FIELD.FieldApiName] : this.naam
```

Further, you need to make sure the property is *not* read-only:

```
@api
naam = 'default';
```

Should be:

```
naam = 'default';
```